# Java - Polimorfismo

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo una duda sobre polimorfismo. Mi consulta es si se puede acceder a métodos de la clase hija creando un objeto de la clase padre (insustancialidad como la clase hija) .

Esta duda surge de querer ocupar un método getter de la clase hija, para mostrar un atributo de la misma, habiendo definido un objeto "**Padre unHijo = new Hijo()**".

Quisiera saber si es un error de comprensión de polimorfismo o me faltaría definir algo mas. Dejo un fragmento de código para ejemplificar mi duda.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Padre unHijo = new Hijo ( "Pepe" );
      System.out.println( unHijo.getNombre() );
   }
}

class Padre {
   public Padre() {
   }
}

class Hijo extends Padre {
   String nombre;
   

   public Hijo(String nombre) {
      this.nombre=nombre;
   }
   public String getNombre (){
      return this.nombre;
   }
}
```

Comment: Y, ¿qué te impide hacer esto: `Hijo unHijo = new Hijo ( "Pepe" );`? Con lo que nos muestras no tiene sentido que la instancia sea del tipo `Padre`. Por otra parte, ¿a qué método de la clase padre querrías acceder y cómo has declarado ese método? Considera poner un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable donde se pueda apreciar el problema que planteas.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos por partes, **Hijo** hereda a **Padre**, pero **Padre** no hereda a **Hijo**.

```
Padre pepe = new Hijo( "pepe" );
```

No crea un objeto de la clase **Padre** sino de la clase **Hijo** (observa que estás llamando al constructor de **Hijo**), ahora bien, todo objeto de una clase hija, es también un objeto de la clase padre, vamos con un ejemplo.

```
public class Animal {
    String nombre;

    public Animal( String nom ) {
        nombre = nom;
    }

    public void desplazarse() {
        
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
}

public class Perro extends Animal {
    public Perro( String nom ) {
        super( nom );
    }

    @override
    public void desplazarse() {
        camina();
    }

    public void darLaPatita() {
        patitar();
    }    
}

public class Tiburon extends Animal {
    public Tiburon( String nom ) {
        super( nom );
    }

    @override
    public void desplazarse() {
        nada();
    }    
}
```

ahora creamos animales de compañia:

```
Perro boby = new Perro( 8, "boby" );
Tiburon toto = new Tiburon( 25, "toto" );
Animal bu = new Animal( 40, "bu" );
```

los enjaulamos:

```
Animal animales[] = { boby, toto, bu };
```

los movemos:

```
      // esto es polimorfismo, osea, el comportamiento está definido por 
      //el tipo del objeto que invoca al método
    boby.desplazarse();   
    toto.desplazarse();   

      // definimos el tipo de bu.
    ((Perro) un ).desplazarse();
```

Ahora bien, si intentas algo como lo siguiente:

```
Animal popo = new Animal( 1, "pp" );
popo.darLaPatita();
```

obtendrás un error, ya que la clase **Animal** no tiene un método **darLaPatita**.

y por último usamos la herencia:

```
for( int i = 0; i < animales.length; i ++ ) {
    System.out.println( animales[ i ].getNombre() );
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero mi pregunta apuntaba mas a un polimorfismo dinámico. Por ejemplo suponiendo que el usuario sea quien elija el tipo de animal que quiera encerrar en su jaula (siguiendo tu ejemplo).

Comment: Por eso mi intencion era generar una jaula capaz de encerrar tanto Perro, como Tiburon, como Animal. Sin necesidad de generar una jaula para cada clase.
Por ejemplo vos pusiste:

`Animal animales[] = { boby, toto, bu };`

En ese caso se podrias acceder al metodo darLaPatita() de boby?

Comment: Si podrías bajo la condición de hacer previamente un casting:  **( (Perro) animales[ 0 ] ).darLaPatita();**.